# SQLite3 - Preventing duplicate entries from being entered into a database

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

First off, apologies in advance in the question I ask is too elementary - I am very much a SQLite neophyte just getting his feet wet and trying to accomplish a simple task with Python and SQLite3.

I have a SQLite database file (`notify_users`) with two text fields: `language_code` and `username`. I'm using this execute code to enter information into the database, e.g.: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO notify_users VALUES ('de', 'jane_doe')")`:

Visualized, then, the database looks like this:

```
| language_code | username      |
---------------------------------
| de            | jane_doe      |
| sv            | jane_doe      |
| de            | tom_petty     |
```

and so on. While it's okay for one username to be associated with multiple language_codes, I'd like to **prevent a duplicate entry** with both the **same language_code and username**.

How should I change the `INSERT INTO` code so that it will **not** make a new entry if it's going to be exactly the same in both fields as one that already exists?

```
| language_code | username      |
---------------------------------
| de            | jane_doe      |
| de            | jane_doe      | X # Don't want this duplicate entry to be entered.
```

Thanks, and please let me know if there's anything I can do to be more precise or specific about this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the database do the work.  Create a unique index.  This will prevent such duplication:

```
create unique index unq_notify_users_2 on notify_users(language_code, username);
```

It prevents duplication by generating an error.  Although it is best to do the check in the database, you can avoid the error by doing something like this:

```
insert into notify_users(language_code, username)
    select language_code, username
    from (select $language_code as language_code, $username as username) lu
    where not exists (select 1
                      from notify_users nu
                      where nu.language_code = lu.language_code and
                            nu.username = lu.username
                     );
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon - is this a separate command that I run? (Forgive my ignorance!)

Comment: @JohnSmith . . . `create index` is something you do in the database, once.  The `insert` is an example of how you can insert data.